# SharePoint Server backup/restore on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, backup, restore

Is it possible to backup sharepoint server backup and restore in on SharePoint online version. Any suitable ways and what can be the compatibility issues if its possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to migrate your on-premise SharePoint content to SharePoint Online? Have you already read this one: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852518.aspx ?

Answer (score 2):

There are migration tools available, but backup-restore is not the way to think about such migrations.

Speaking of compatibility issues, you can only use the out-of-the-box site definitions and site templates, no farm solutions, no files deployed to web application resources, _layouts or _controltemplates virtual directories, and even in sandboxed solutions all managed code is deprecated. JavaScript and CSS customizations may also be fragile due to breaking changes being sometimes introduced by Microsoft without prior notice.

It is recommended that you base most of your development targeted at SharePoint Online off of Team Site, not even Blank Site.

Answer (score 1):

You can not backup restore to SharePoint Online since you do not have access to the (SQL) databases.

There are some 3th party tools available to migrate content but in my opinion none of those tools does the job really well.

Custom SharePoint (Visual Studio) solutions can not be migrated. Sandbox solutions with .NET code can not be migrated.